# apache poi---How to read password protected .doc file using java code?

Tags: apache-poi

How to read password protected .doc file using java code??

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.extractor.WordExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
public class MsFileReader 
{
    public static void readDocFile(String fileName) 
    {

       try 
        {
              File file = new File(fileName);
              InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
              HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);
              WordExtractor we = new WordExtractor(doc);
              String[] paragraphs = we.getParagraphText();
              System.out.println("Total no of paragraph "+paragraphs.length);
              for (String para : paragraphs) 
              {
                     System.out.println(para.toString());
              }

             fis.close();
         } catch (Exception e) 
         {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Test.doc is password encrypted file
        //after running this code it throws exception
        //EncryptedDocumentException
        readDocFile("C:\\Test.doc");
    }
}
```

I want java code to read password encrypted .doc file.
I get EncryptedDocumentException at HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fis);

Comment: Is this a question, an answer, or both?

Comment: I am not able to read password protected .doc file using above code(I know password of file, but i want to read it using java), its throwing exception EncryptedDocumentException!!!

Comment: Click the edit button below your question and add all that in. Your question is likely to be closed soon because it is incomplete as it stands.

Comment: Also, what were you expecting? It's password protected.

Comment: This might be helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31676281/apache-poi-decrypt-doc-file-cannot-process-encrypted-file

Comment: Any other library i can use to read this .doc file. I need java code.

Comment: I've implemented the de-/encryption in the meantime - check [the factory class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45238486#45337641) for handling doc/docx